# Making iPhone App iOS 5 Compatible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have developed the app using Base SDK 4.3.

I want to make sure my app is iOS 5 compatible.

In that case, should I change my base SDK to 5.0 or keep it at 4.3 and test it in iPhone 5 Simulator?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your depoloyment target to 5.0, your app will be only available for devices that run iOS 5.0. Keep it at 4.3 (edit: sorry, you're talking about base sdk here, but still leave your depoloyment as is) and test in the iOS 5 Simulator. You should definately do the same to a device with iOS 5.0 as well! (Your base sdk is not relevant in your case -- change it to 5.0 if you need to use APIs from 5.0)

[More about deployement targets here](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done on mine:

Once you installed the latest version of xCode 4.2, you can't go back to SDK 4.3.

A.  So Base SDK will be set at SDK 5.0.
B.  If you still want to support iOS 4.3 devices then set your "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 4.3 or whatever minimum version you still want to support.
C.  Now you can test your app on Simulator/devices with iOS 4.3 or whatever minimum version and iOS 5.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to make sure test on a real device instead of simulator. 
Second, you should compile for iOS 5.0 and check any errors/warnings. 
Third, you can set iOS Deployment Target for 4.3 and test on 5.0 simulator